# can i use viewbag.somedata in editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

Hy guys i have a question. How to use viewdata/bag for show data from db in editor?

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
         {
            @Html.Editor(ViewBag.Task1,"Task1");
            @Html.Editor(ViewBag.Task2,"Task2");
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
         }
```

like this. It shows me error

Comment: What error it shows?

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of `@Html.Editor` is `string` so if you want to render a textbox with the value of `ViewBag.Task1` use

```
@Html.Editor("Task1");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i found the answer of my question, i can declare string variable as viewbag.somedata and i can use this variable in editor

here:


          @{string task1 = ViewBag.Task1;string task2 = ViewBag.Task2}


           @using (Html.BeginForm())
           {
            @Html.Editor(task1,"Task1");
            @Html.Editor(task2,"Task2");           
            <input type="submit" value="Save">
           }
```